# How to add simple debug to Application using preprocessor defines

Tags: c++, c

I am developing a GUI app on WinXP but unfortunately std::cerr/cout goes nowhere.  I would like to add a simple debug method that appends messages to a log file.

I have been hashing together an almost workable solution reading other posts.  And am able to have a single debug() method call in my GUI app.  However, don't even get that far in the below example app I am trying to use to find a solution.

Using:

- Dev-C++ v4.9.9.2
- WinXP

Below is the structure of my example app:

```
C:.
|   Makefile.win
|   Project1.dev
|
\---src
    |   bar.cpp
    |   bar.h
    |   foo.cpp
    |   foo.h
    |   main.cpp
    |
    +---inc
    |       debug.h
    |
    \---log
```

src/bar.h:

```
#ifndef BAR_H
#define BAR_H

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar();  
};
#endif
```

src/bar.cpp:

```
#include "bar.h"

Bar::Bar()
{
//    debug("I am Bar.");
}
```

src/foo.h and src/foo.cpp are the same except change 'Bar' to 'Foo'

Using information that I have found in other articles...

src/inc/debug.h:

```
#ifndef MY_DEBUG_H
#define MY_DEBUG_H

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#ifndef LOGFILE
#define LOGFILE std::ofstream logfile("log/debug.txt", std::ios::app);
#endif

#ifndef debug
#define debug(s) LOGFILE << "[" << __DATE__ << " " << __TIME__ \
            << "] " << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << " " << s << std::endl

#endif

#endif
```

src/main.cpp:

```
#include "inc/debug.h"
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    debug("Starting program."); 
    Foo *f = new Foo();
    Bar *b = new Bar();
}
```

When I attempt to compile this I get an error at the `debug("Starting program.");` line in main.cpp saying `expected primary-expression before '<<' token`.

Could someone tell me what causes this error and also a good way to then be able to apply debug messages in other files/classes i.e. uncomment the lines:

```
//    debug("I am Bar.");
//    debug("I am Foo.");
```

in bar.cpp and foo.cpp respectively and use debug() anywhere else?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "*unfortunately std::cerr/cout goes nowhere*" What does this mean exactly..?

Comment: @ildjarn - it means that in a Windows GUI application you don't have a console, unless you explicitly call [AllocConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @BoPersson : But his entrypoint is `main`, not `WinMain`.

Comment: @ildjarn - I didn't read all the code but trusted "I am developing a GUI app ".  :-)

Comment: @BoPersson : Fair enough. Apparently the opposite for me. :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your define for logfile is messed up.

When your code is preprocessed you'll get:

```
std::ofstream logfile("log/debug.txt", std::ios::app); << "[" << __DATE__ << " " << __TIME__ \
        << "] " << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << " " << "Starting Program" << std::endl;
```

What you would need to do is something like this in a header file:

```
extern std::ofstream LOG_FILE;
```

and in some cpp file (perhaps your main.cpp file):

```
#include "debug.h"
std::ofstream LOG_FILE("log/debug.txt",std::ios::app);
```

To disable debugging you could do something like:

```
#define debug(ignore)((void) 0)
```

When your debug flag isn't enabled compared to your other debug definition.

You could also put the class initialization in a similar `#ifdef` block to avoid opening the file when you aren't using it.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I have put the 'extern std::ofstream LOG_FILE' statement into debug.h.  Is this an ok way to go or would it be better practice to create a separate header file?

Comment: @ZettaiMuri: Putting it in debug.h is fine just make sure you initialize it in a cpp file

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I am initializing it in main.cpp.  Is there a way to implement this so that I could turn the debug messages on & off at runtime?

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner at C++ so I am wondering how to use that at runtime. Wouldn't '#define debug(ignore)((void) 0)' turn off debugging when i recompiled the code with this statement present? Or would it be possible for example to select a menu option like 'Setup > Turn off Debug' while the app is running?

Answer (score 0):

Tbh you might almost as well replace cout/cerr output to just point directly to a file. For example see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/rdbuf/ for an example. Then just use cout/cerr as normal. You might have to be careful about flushing etc, at least if you want to read it in real time.